# Stata JDBC PostgreSQL mystery bug

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, stata

I've launched a cloud PostgreSQL database at my organization and have had a few users test it. I thought it best to have my users use JDBC rather than ODBC in Stata to connect to the DB, as it saves them a trip to IT to install the driver. My users are all using the latest version of the PostgreSQL driver and the latest release of Stata 17, and all on Windows.

Strangely, I am able to access the database from Stata 17 and Stata 18 without issue. Two of my users, however, get the following error when they run `jdbc connect`:

```
invalid connection property key value pair
     Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
r(198);
```

It seems to me that this error is coming from the underlying Java Runtime, not Stata itself, as the error message is exactly the text of an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Java. In fact, these same users are able to access the DB using R, Python, and - get this - Java code compiled and run from the command line with Stata's own built-in Java Runtime environment! I have even tried modifying Stata-Java's logging.properties file (as per these instructions https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/logging/) to create logs for the PostgreSQL driver in my affected users' home directories, but even that doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be going on here? Many many thanks in advance!

Comment: Not familiar with stata, though since it is only on two users a few things I would check: is the error purely related to the connection, did they configure pre/post-steps connection (if at all possible), have you tried fresh install of it on those two? Do they have different JRE installed? Do they have different versions of JDBC libs installed? The log part I would check the stata tool itself if possible to configure logging rather than the connector. These are suggestions to take a look.

Comment: Familiar with Stata, but less with Java. You can ask each user to run `java query` in the Stata command line to get detailed info if Java if initialized and versions. Perhaps this gives a clue.